# Xcode 4 mach-o error

Tags: c++, macos, linker, xcode4, mach-o

I coded an OSX application (not for iphone) on top of another, changed the name properly (I was even asked if I wanted to rename all instances of the original name, and did). It compiles perfectly when I am not producing an executable, but when I do the later, it fails because its looking for a target named with the previous name of the application.

The actual faulty section of the compile process goes like this:

... build previousName.xcodeProj ....

What do I have to change so that xcode(4) stops looking for a project with the original name of the application?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while ago. Restarting Xcode was all I needed to do.

Comment: That would do it in some other cases, not this one though. Anyway, I gave up and did it in another way, with another library that did the same I needed. Honestly this was nothing short of a nightmare